# How to get the last 3 distinct ids from a mysql table

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, greatest-n-per-group

[image: Database]

Ok so basically I have my database table.  The first column is the id.  The second is a pkg_id.  The 3rd is not important and the 4th is the previous id that the pkg_id was located at.  I need to pull the last 3 pkg_id's from the table.  So basically I need to pull the last 3 17879 pkg_id's and the last 3 3075.  So in this example I need to pull id 9 , 7 , 6 for 17879 and id 8, 5, 3 for 3075.

I can't get my head around it.  I do have access to the previous id that it was.  So you see that for id 9 it says that 17879 was last in id 7.  That id 8 was last in id 5.

If anybody could help me write a query that would be great.  I'm also using Java for database access so it doesn't have to be just in mysql.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  m.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  pkg_id,
                COALESCE(
                (
                SELECT  id
                FROM    mytable mi
                WHERE   mi.pkg_id = md.pkg_id
                ORDER BY
                        id DESC
                LIMIT 2, 1
                ), 0) AS mid
        FROM    (
                SELECT  DISTINCT pkg_id
                FROM    mytable
                ) md
        ) q
JOIN    mytable m
ON      m.pkg_id <= q.pkg_id
        AND m.pkg_id >= q.pkg_id
        AND m.id >= q.mid
```

Create an index on `mytable (pkg_id, id)` for this to work fast.

Note this condition: `m.pkg_id <= q.pkg_id AND m.pkg_id >= q.pkg_id` instead of mere `m.pkg_id = q.pkg_id`. This is required for the index to be used efficiently.

Comment: Holy freaking crap.  How in the world do you come up with this?  Your SQL kung fu is strong.  Amazing!!  Thank you so much!!